# How to find a file in a directory while in bash script without using find command

Tags: bash, directory

I currently have two bash scripts, assign1.bash and read.bash, and a directory called data (which holds txt files with information about courses in them). assign 1 creates a menu and asks if you want to read a file, if chosen it executes ./read.bash

read.bash prompts the user for input for course code and course number
it then checks if the file exists in the data directory, if it does it will read it line by line and print out values read in. if it does not exist, it simply prints an error.

My code currently checks if the file is found, then it has a blank line, after hitting enter 5 times it prints but with only one value.

I've tried taking the input and making the filename i'm looking for in the data directory by using:
   `course_file=data"${dept_code^^}$course_num".crs`

but this causes the blank lines

```sh
#!/bin/bash

  #need an if statement here to check if the course exists
  read -p "Enter a department code and course number:" dept_code course_num
  course_file=data/"${dept_code^^}$course_num".crs
  if [[ -f "$course_file" ]]; then
    read dept_code dept_name
    read course_name
    read course_sched course_start course_end
    read course_hours
    read course_size


  else
    echo "ERROR: course not found"
  fi
    echo "Course department: $dept_code $dept_name"
  echo "Course number: $course_num"
  echo "Course name: $course_name"
  echo "Sheduled days: $course_sched"
  echo "Course start: $course_start"
  echo "Course end: $course_end"
  echo "Credit hours: $course_hours"
  echo "Enrolled Students: $course_size"
  assign1.bash
```

A course file that exists in directory is CS3423,
 so if the user inputs: cs 3423
it should check if it exists inside of data (CS3423.crs exists in data directory) then read the information line by line taking in the variables declared

it should then print out the following:

```
Course number: 3423
Course name: Systems programming
Sheduled days: MWF
Course start: 7/20/19
Course end: 10/20/19
Credit hours: 3
Enrolled Students: 43
```

then return to the original prompt in assign1.bash which is a menu asking if you want to read a file

Comment: I forgot to add that I am not allowed to use the find command

Answer (score 0):

`ls` and [file globbing](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/globbingref.html) or `grep` may be a good solution for this, if you do not need to recurse through the `data/` directory structure (as `find` does).

You can attempt a "fuzzy" match on the file by doing something like the following:

```sh
# With globbing.
$ ls data/
1234.crs 2345.crs 3456.crs
$ ls data/*23*.crs
1234.crs 2345.crs

# With grep.
$ ls data/
1234.crs 2345.crs 3456.crs
$ ls data/ | grep "23"
1234.crs
2345.crs
```

The advantage of globbing is that there is no piping involved, so it may be a tiny bit faster, but that's likely negligible for this.

Comment: How could I possibly add that ls data/ globbing into an if statement for the file check? Also, do you have any suggestions for reading the variables in line by line?